# Two Matrices multiplication in c[turbo c++]

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    int a[9][9],b[9][9],c[9][9],i,j,m,n,p,q,k;
    
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter the order of the first matrix:");
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
    printf("Enter the order of the second matrix:");
    scanf("%d%d",&p,&q);
    
    if(p==n)
    {
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                printf("enter1st matrix element of row %d & column %d:",i+1,j+1);
                scanf("%d",a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<p;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<q;j++)
            {
                printf("enter 2nd matrix element of row %d & column %d:",i+1,j+1);
                scanf("%d",b[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n;i++)
            {
                c[i][j]=0;
                for(k=0;k<p;k++)
                {
                    c[i][j]=c[i][j]+a[i][k]*b[k][j];
                }
            }
            for(i=0;i<m;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<q;j++)
                {
                    printf("%d\t",c[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Matrix multiplication is invalid !...");
    }
    getch();
}
```

**It has no error while compile but it while running it doesn't show the multiplied matrices as desired it get inputs but not giving an output

Find the mistakes and answer it**

Comment: What do you expect from a scanf format %d%d ?

Comment: Turbo C++ is a C++ compiler. (Sort of.  It's *way* obsolete relative to the current C++ standard.)  C++ is not C, even if you write in C-like idiom.  I have updated your tags.

Comment: But if you were actually interested in C, as opposed to C++, then there are good, modern C compilers available free of charge for every operating system I know.

Comment: You're reusing the same variables for multiple nested loops. This is usually not the intent. What you *did* intend was to output the result after the multiplication has completed, but you did it inside the multiplication loop.

Comment: Whatever language you're targeting, I urge you to use more descriptive variable names.  Single-letter names make it a lot harder to recognize errors.

Answer (score 0):

In the actual multiplication loop nest, you have incorrect loop bounds.  That won't matter when both matrices are square, but it will at best give you incorrect results when one or both are rectangular.  Additionally, you have a typo in the loop counter increment (thanks, @Bob__).

Given that `m` is the first dimension of the left matrix (`a`), `q` is the second dimension of the right matrix (`b`), and `n` == `p` is the common dimension of the two, the multiplication should look like this:

```
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < q; j++) {  // note loop bound change here
                c[i][j] = 0;

                for (k = 0; k < p; k++) {
                    c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                }
            }
            // ...
```

Comment: Answer updated to address the typo in the increment